# How to add a new textfield on button click and add integer value of that input field to an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a new input field on button click and add the integer value of that input field to an array in react

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState([])
const [count, setCount] = useState([1])

const addNewTextField = () => setCount(prev => [...prev,1])

const addInputValue= () => {
   setPrice()
   console.log(price)
}

<Button onClick={addNewTextField}>Add TextField</Button >
{
   count.map((item, i) => {
   return (
    <TextField   key={i} value={item.value} id={i}  type='text' />
      )
    })
 } 

<Button onClick={addInputValue}>submit</Button >
```

first input value is  100,
second input value is  200,
result should be like this when I add new input field:
`[100,200]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. You can keep only `price` state.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState([""]);

  const addNewTextField = () => setPrice((prev) => [...prev, ""]);

  const addInputValue = (i, newValue) => {
    console.log(i, newValue);
    setPrice((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((value, valueIndex) =>
        valueIndex === i ? newValue : value
      )
    );
  };

  console.log(price);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addNewTextField}>Add TextField</button>;
      {price.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <input
            key={i}
            placeholder={`input ${i}`}
            // value={item}
            id={i}
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => addInputValue(i, e.target.value)}
          />
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={addInputValue}>submit</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-minsky-gi64b?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @asif kaif, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

```
   const [price, setPrice] = useState([]);
   const [count, setCount] = useState([1]);
   const [value, setValue] = useState("");
            
   const addNewTextField = () => setCount(prev => [...prev,prev + 1]);
            
   const addInputValue= () => {
         setPrice(price.concat(value));
         console.log(price)
   }
        
   return(   
    <div>
       <Button onClick={addNewTextField}>Add TextField</Button >
       {
         count.map((item, i) => {
         return (
             <TextField   key={i} value={value} id={i}  type='text' 
             onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
         );
       })
     } 
            
      <Button onClick={addInputValue}>submit</Button >
    </div>
  );
```

Button and TextField components:

```
function Button(props){
   return(
   <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</button>
);
}

function TextField(props){
   return(
     <input type="text" id={props.id} value={props.value}
     onChange={e=>props.onChange(e)}>
);
}
```